# Reset Filter In AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, filter

I am trying to reset my filters by clicking a button. I have tried setting the values to empty but all that does is completely delete the list of options. I would like to be able to set them to empty and reuse them again after without having to reset my web app.

My JS.

```
$scope.resetFilters = function() {

        $scope.itemCat = {};

    }
```

My HTML.

```
<div class="card-header">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h1>Current Postings</h1>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="resetFilters()">Reset Filters</button>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                    <label for="searchByName">Filter by Keyword:</label><input type="text" id="searchByName"
                        class="form-control" ng-model="filteritem.itemName">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                    <label for="searchByCat">Filter by Category:</label><select
                        class="form-control" id="searchByCat" ng-options="value for value in itemCat"
                        ng-model="filteritem.itemCat">
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                    <label for="searchByLocation">Filter by Location:</label><input
                        type="text" id="searchByLocation" class="form-control" ng-model="filteritem.location">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

HTML that my filter affects.

```
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="item in items | filter : filteritem">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{item.thumbnail}}"
                        class="card-img-top img-fluid">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{item.itemName}}</h4>
                        <p class="text-success">{{'$' + item.itemPrice}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            <small class="text-muted">{{item.location}}</small> <br>
                        </p>

                    </div>
                    <button type="button" ng-click="selectItem(item)"
                        class="btn btn-danger">View Item</button>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$scope.itemCat = {};` try `$scope.filteritem.itemCat=null;`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the list of categories to empty instead of the filter fields.

Remove this:

`$scope.itemCat = {};`

And replace it with:

```
$scope.filteritem.itemName = null;
$scope.filteritem.itemCat = null;
$scope.filteritem.location = null;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason. I'm getting this error angular.js:14800 TypeError: Cannot set property 'itemName' of undefined. I added more HTML to my post. I tried $scope.filter.itemName = null; once before thinking it would work. But to no avail.

Comment: Can you post where `$scope.filteritem` is defined in your controller? The error is suggesting itemName does not exist

Comment: I don't have it specified in my JS anywhere. My filters do work however.

Comment: In that case, what happens if you set `$scope.filteritem = null` in your resetFilters method?

Comment: itemName comes from my http request done in angularJS. I'm making a request to my server which then gets the data from my database and responds back to my front end with (items). I'm the using ng-repeat="item in items | filter : filteritem" to populate these items on my view. To filter items based off of their itemName, itemCat or location I'm using the 3 Inputs in my html to do so.

Comment: Nothing happens. Zero errors but none of the filters clear.